# How does std::vector resize its internal buffer?

Tags: c++, stl

As far as I know, C++ does not support an operator like 'realloc(void *, size_t)' in C language.

However, std::vector should have a buffer to contain data, and the buffer should be expanded or compacted.

Then how could it be done to resize the buffer of std::vector without 'realloc' function?

Is it be done just by allocating new buffer, copy or move all elements and destructing previous buffer?
I think it is inefficient.

Comment: It creates new memory, then moves the elements (move or copy constructor call). Besides, there 's HeapReAlloc (and some equivalent in other systems) that would realloc if that was the method. Even if it used realloc, unless the items were satisfiying TriviallyCopyable they couldn't be copied by memcpy.

Comment: "As far as I know, C++ does not support an operator like 'realloc(void *, size_t)' in C language" - yes, it does. C++ is compatible with C in this regard. Of course, you almost certainly don't want to use it in C++ code.

Comment: The problem with `realloc` is that it only works if memory can be expanded w/o changing the previously allocated and likely used memory. This is memory fragmentation and OS dependent

Comment: All standard containers that don't have a fixed number of elements (`std::vector`, `std::list`, etc) make requests to an object called an allocator, which does the actual work of memory management, via a defined interface. Allocators and containers tend to be pretty carefully crafted for performance and correctness by the authors of your standard library (or compiler vendor). Before claiming they are inefficient, write code of your own that does the same thing, get it working correctly, and compare. (Beginners tend to over-estimate their ability to write efficient and correct code).

Comment: @Peter, as far the allocators are concerned, their implementation is rather simple. It's vector<> and the containers themselves that don't allocate all the time (or allocate exponentially to cope with future growth). The allocators simply call new or malloc or OS-dependend function and yes there is potential to implement them more efficiently (memory pools etc).

Answer (score 6):

> As far as I know, C++ does not support an operator like 'realloc(void *, size_t)'

C++ does have `std::realloc`. But it is not (typically?) used to implement resizing of vector.

> Then how could it be done to resize the buffer of std::vector without 'realloc' function?

Using following algorithm:

- allocate new array
- copy or move contents to the new array
- deallocate old array

> Is it be done just by allocating new buffer, copy or move all elements and destructing previous buffer?

Yes.

> I think it is inefficient.

Why do you think so? That's *exactly* what `realloc` does. Sure, `realloc` may *sometimes* be able to skip the copying depending on memory layout, which vector generally cannot. This is an unfortunate downside of vector compared to manually `malloc`ated dynamic array, but it's not necessarily a significant downside.

There have been proposals to add reallocation support to standard allocators, which would allow the same optimisation if adopted into the standard: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p0894r1.md

Comment: It moves the contents, it doesn't copy them (Calls move constructor if there).

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis it does one or the other depending on type of element.

Answer (score 2):

std::realloc is *never* used unless the container knows that the objects are TriviallyCopiable.

Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc

> Because reallocation may involve bytewise copying (regardless of
>   whether it's to expand or to contract), only the objects of
>   TriviallyCopyable types are safe to access in the preserved part of
>   the memory block after a call to realloc.
>
> Some non-standard libraries define a type trait "BitwiseMovable" or
>   "Relocatable", which describes a type that doesn't have:

If the container cannot know that the objects are trivially copiable, then using realloc to expand the memory might result in corrupted data.

If [is_trivially_copiable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) can be used on the container, then yes, using realloc is possible. Otherwise it will led to undefined behaviour.

Otherwise, the container a) creates new memory, b) calls copy or move constructor of the elements to move them to new memory c) frees old memory.

Comment: Because in C, all types are trivially copiable.

Comment: Trivial copiability is not the only problem. The implementation would also have to know that the allocator gives a pointer from `malloc`.

Comment: @eerorika, yes but the implementation family of functions would use the same class of functions (e.g. alloc from malloc, realloc from realloc() etc, or alloc from HeapAlloc and realloc from HeapReAlloc) - I Guess.

Answer (score 0):

In case of a `std::vector<bool>` in theory there is nothing against the fact an equivalent of *realloc* is used internally, but looking at the implementation for g++ ( gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 / Raspbian ):

```
  template<typename _Alloc>
    void
    vector<bool, _Alloc>::
    _M_reallocate(size_type __n)
    {
      _Bit_pointer __q = this->_M_allocate(__n);
      iterator __start(std::__addressof(*__q), 0);
      this->_M_impl._M_finish = _M_copy_aligned(begin(), end(), __start);
      this->_M_deallocate();
      this->_M_impl._M_start = __start;
      this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage = __q + _S_nword(__n);
    }
```

so it is based on a new allocation then copy then deallocation

Comment: Using realloc will fail, see my answer below.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis notice my answer is about vector of bool, and I suppose bool is TriviallyCopyable no ;-) ?

Comment: Yes, if the type is some POD it will work. But usually it's not the case.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis so this is the case here and "_In theory there is nothing against the fact an equivalent of realloc is used internally_" is not wrong, anyway you DV my answer (I suppose is you)

Comment: The OP did not confine his container to bool, so anyone that sees it might assume it is safe everywhere - remember that lots of newbies in C++ would read your answer as a man with high reputation.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I am not sure to know how to follow you, you DV me because someone can wrongly read my answer ? is that a joke ? Out of that the reputation doesn't not protect against error ^^

Comment: I DV because of that
"In theory there is nothing against the fact an equivalent of realloc is used internally"
This is incorrect.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis this is correct for the vector<bool> my answer speak about !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193219/discussion-between-michael-chourdakis-and-bruno).

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis why do you propose me to go in the chat and stay silent in ? grrr

Answer (score -1):

**std::vector** has a [resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) function that allows you to expand or compact the array as needed.  If a reallocation does occur, it copy/moves the elements to the new allocation automatically.  This is a reason why iterators can become invalid.

Comment: and the question is about that, or equivalent (`push_back` ...)

Comment: I do not DV but I do not understand the reason of your answer (even it is not false :-) )

Comment: @bruno.  Interesting.  It looks to me like the Op is trying to figure out how to resize a vector manually.   How do you interpret the question?

Comment: The question is about the implementation of vector::resize, not how to use vector operations to resize one